# Access jquery data in laravel controller

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, nginx

I am getting a problem with accessing data from ajax in my laravel controller.
My code works on local with Apache but not on server with nginx (dont know if this is the issue) 
If I do it with a static SQL request it works but I need to access the data dynamically.

The http route is ok but in controller doesn´t get the data.

My contorller function:

```
public function readHSauswahl(Request $request){

        $data = Message::where('name', '=', $request->title)->get();

        return response()->json($data);
```

my route:

```
Route::get('/readHSauswahl', 'AjaxController@readHSauswahl');
```

and the ajax call:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url:'{!!URL::to('/readHSauswahl')!!}',
        dataType: "json",
        data:{'title':hochschule_name},
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
...
```

maybe this could have to do with in the nginx config??

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /var/www/html/mydata/public;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name http://www.mydomain.de;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?query_string;
    }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index index.php;         
        include fastcgi_params;
        }

}
```

Edit: 
Changed the routes as suggested. Still works local but not on server.

Tried in the controller:

```
$data1 = $_GET['title'];
//internal server error

$data = $request->input('title'); 
//same behaviour as before
```

Comment: seems like `url:'{!!URL::to('/readHSauswahl')!!}',` is not producing correct url to hit. try hard-coded url once

Comment: thanks for the comment. but it is the right url. checked it in chromes network log

Answer (score 1):

It's better to name your route

```
Route::get('/readHSauswahl', 'AjaxController@readHSauswahl')->name('readhsa');
```

And in your ajax set url with using `route()` helper

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'get',
  url:'{{route('readhsa')}}',
});
```